# Is there a way to avoid shaking effect, when angular loads dynamically build pages?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I'm new to Angular JS and programming in general. I have ng-repeat which loops through json, loaded with "$http" service, building-up vertical menu.
 I have several pages, which are builded dynamically by angular. The problem is that when I'm navigating through those pages, browser scroll bar dissapears (since there's nothing to scroll, while the page is half-build), just to appear again in some half of a second. As a result whole page is shaking and irritates me deadly.
 Up until now I was always able to find solution to my newbie troubles myself. But looks like there's no much information on this issue on web. (Which, most probably means, that the question is dumb ;)

P.S. Thank you, and sorry for my English.

Comment: If you expect the data not to fit into the window most of the time, one of the solutions is to have the scrollbar on all the time. Your English is great, btw.

Comment: well, I've got only one of five pages, that will fit in the window (if we're talking of 1360x768), but it looks like, I'm able to make scroll bar visible from pages controllers. So I'll use your solution, if I'll find no better. 

P.S. Thanks a lot,  Didn't even know, that browser's scroll bar is accessable from CSS :)
There actually is another workaround. I figured out, that there is no "shake effect", if I'm fetching data for my nav-menu from angular .constant since it applies sooner, but of course, that's not a solution.

Comment: If you've not considered it already, give **[ng-cloak](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak)** a shot.

Comment: I've tried to use ng-cloak before, but that wasn't working. Now I figured out why. I was missing "!important" in my CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Using `ng-cloak` solved my issue. I've found that it was not working properly because, something in my CSS was more specific than `ng-cloak` attribute selector. So I included `!important` rule in my CSS.

```
[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], .ng-cloak {
display: none !important;
}
```